# Jib: Missing target image parameter

Tags: spring, maven, microservices, jib

I'm trying to Dockerize Spring Microservices application with the help of Jib.
Config of parent pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.nikonenko</groupId>
<artifactId>microservices</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>library-service</module>
    <module>book-service</module>
    <module>discovery-server</module>
    <module>api-gateway</module>
    <module>config-service</module>
    <module>authentication-service</module>
</modules>

<name>microservices</name>
<description>..</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    *dependencies*
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>registry.hub.docker.com/viktordiktor/${project.artifactId}</image>
                </to>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>dockerBuild</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So, when I'm use `mvn clean compile jib:build`, I'm getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.0:build (default-cli) on
> project library-service: Missing target image parameter, perhaps you
> should add a  configuration parameter to your pom.xml or
> set the parameter via the commandline (e.g. 'mvn compile jib:build
> -Dimage='). -> [Help 1]

I also changed my settings.xml file:

```
<servers>
    <id>registry.hub.docker.com</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>pass</password>
</servers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to propagate the invocation of a plugin to the modules of a multi-module Maven project, you need to put it to the [`pluginManagement`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugin-management) block of the parent POM:

```xml
  <build>
    <!-- Defines plugins that are used in the modules. -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

See [an example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/examples/multi-module) provided by Jib.

Comment: No result. Same error message.

Comment: Did you reference the plugin in your submodules as per `pluginManagement` documentation I linked?