# Jib Maven Plugin Error: "Missing target image parameter" When Building Docker Image

Tags: java, docker, maven, jib

I'm working on a Maven project and trying to build a Docker image using the Jib Maven plugin. However, when I run the build command, I encounter a 'Missing target image parameter' error. I've checked my pom.xml configuration and everything seems to be in order, but the build still fails. I'm not sure what's missing or incorrect.

Error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Missing target image parameter, perhaps you should add a <to><image> configuration parameter to your pom.xml or set the parameter via the command line (e.g., 'mvn compile jib:build -Dimage=<your image name>').
```

Command I used:

```
mvn -X compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build
```

pom.xml configuration (of microservice-parent):

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>registry.hub.docker.com/username/${project.artifactId}:latest</image>
                </to>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

settings.xml Configuration:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository/>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>registry.hub.docker.com</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors/>
    <proxies/>
    <profiles/>
    <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

I've ensured that my Maven settings are correctly configured and that I'm in the right directory when running the command. I'm not behind a proxy, and my internet connection is stable.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? Are there any additional configurations or steps I might be missing? Any suggestions on what might be wrong or what else I can check would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've mentioned `microservice-parent`, so you have a multi-module project, right? Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77720851/16417367) help to resolve your issue?

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you. After that, it started to giving a 401 error, so, I removed "credsStore": "desktop", from .docker/config.json and it worked.